# MVC3 EE CTP - Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities

I have small MVC 3 Entity code first application, I created table in my local database and took the backup of table and restored the data on winhost web hosting database.

In my web.config I have change connection string to winhost connection starting. it wrosk on my desktop.

I transferred my local application to windows, when access the application I am getting this error.

error coming from this method.

```
  public ActionResult ListRecords()
        {
            var query = from e in db.Envelopes
                        orderby e.ReportDate descending
                        select e;
            IEnumerable<Envelopes> top10 = query.Take(25);

            return View(top10.ToList<Envelopes>());
        }
```

Error message:

```
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.]
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue) +5025863
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +132
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) +98
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString) +64
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) +24
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(String connectionString, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions) +150
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(String value) +59
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) +4
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name) +399
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() +49
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ConnectionHasModel() +10
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +252
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +16
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +16
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +61
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_Provider() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +13
   System.Linq.Queryable.OrderByDescending(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 keySelector) +66
   Envelopesonly.Controllers.HomeController.ListRecords() in HomeController.cs:84
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +188
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +56
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +267
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +20
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +190
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +329
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +115
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +94
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +31
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8841105
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

Any help fixing this error?

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 0):

Why are you still using the CTP?  The release has been out for quite some time.  Upgrade, then see if your problem persists.  It may be a fixed problem.

Comment: I am using latest version entity framework look like problem with   Linq parsing.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace points out that there is a problem with your connection string.

Fix your connection string, and the problem should dissapear.

Comment: same connection string works on my local machine, it fails in winhost web server

Comment: @sfgroups: Maybe it gets the connection string from somewhere else? The connection string might be empty?